# Eclipse Debug not opening window

Tags: java, eclipse

I have decided to start learning Java. And i have downloaded and is using Eclipse as my code editor. I am also following a tutorial on Youtube and on various sites, and on all of those sites it says that clicking Debug will run your application with live code editing. However, When i press debug my application doesn't launch (i think) but when i click Run, the window shows up and the application is functioning.

So basically what happens when i press Debug is it gives me a list of all currently active Applications, but my application won't open up.

I am on a Mac if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking on an executable file and select Debug As → Java Application. After you have started the application once via the context menu, you can use the created launch configuration again via the Debug button in the Eclipse toolbar.

Comment: sorry, im pretty new at this eclipse program. But in the dropdown menu next to the Debug button, there is a Debug as button, and in there, there's a "1 Java Application" option, is that what i need to do? cause i've done that but its not working

Comment: The "1 Java Application" just states that you have one launch configuration. What happened when you tried out what I wrote?

Comment: i don't really understand what you mean by "right clicking on an executable file"

Comment: Right click on your Main.java file or whatever file that is in your project :)

Comment: same thing happens, it brings up the debug perspective, but no application is opened and the System.out.println message i have does not appear in the console

Comment: same :/ @daniellarsson

Comment: do you think it'd help if i posted a video of the problem? or do you understand what it is?

Comment: @SimonAndersson or u can post the screenshot, it may also help to find out the cause

Comment: 1: Haven't pressed debug or run yet: http://prntscr.com/2204hz
2: Pressed the debug button: http://prntscr.com/2204m3
3: Pressed the run button: http://prntscr.com/2204pl

Comment: What happens if you click the play button? The one that is only there in debug mode.

Comment: @daniellarsson the 3rd picture is right after pressing the play button (green button with a > symbol in it)

Comment: And what if you click the debug play button, the one three steps to the right? Next to the pause and stop buttons.

Answer (score 1):

A complete Debugging tutorial can be found here, will be useful to you.
[Eclipse Debugging](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/)